# Redux with thunks and show data on jsx

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating a chat bot and I have a problem with how to display my messages, Basically I had the following logic using redux, dispatch the user to type and send the message: Where will I have an await variable to leave my textarea disabled until my chat sends the answer and I have my dispatch in which my bot responds to the message, but I am having difficulties with how I will display this on my jsx inside my chatbody:

action:

```
export const sendMessage = text => ({
  type: ON_MESSAGE,
  text,
});

export const botMessage = text => ({
  type: BOT_MESSAGE,
  text,
});

export const awaitAwnser = () => ({
  type: AWAIT_MESSAGE,
});
export const finish = () => ({
  type: FINISH,
});

export const checkMessage = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendMessage(text));

    dispatch(botMessage(verify(text)));

    dispatch(finish());
  };
};
```

my reducer:

```
const initalState = {
  textUser: [],
  textBot: [],
  user: false,
  bot: false,
  await: false,
};

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        textUser: action.text,
        user: true,
        bot: false,
        await: true,
      };
    case BOT_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        textBot: action.text,
        bot: true,
        user: false,
        await: false,
      };
    case FINISH:
      return {
        ...state,
        await: false,
        bot: false,
        user: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my jsx code:

```
 <Styled.ChatLog>
    <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
  </Styled.ChatLog>
  <Styled.ChatInput>
    <textarea
      disabled={messages.await ? true : false}
      onKeyPress={e => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          console.log('ae');
          handleClick();
        }
      }}
      value={text}
      onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem"
    />
```

I need to show all messages typed by user and all replies sent by my chat on my chatlog

Comment: Currently you are replacing `textUser` in your `messageReducer` with `text` every time `dispatch(sendMessage(text));` is called. is this what you expect to happen? it looks like you may want to add that text to `textUser` rather than replace the entire thing (in which case your reducer should look like: ```case ON_MESSAGE: return {...state, textUser: [...state.textUser, action.text], etc```

Comment: yes i wanted to store the text

basically when a user types something and sends it i show it on the screen and leave my textarea as desable and then the bot responds and the text area is enabled again

but I'm in doubt as I will show the user's and bot's msg

Comment: so how are you displaying the messages from the users?? I see value of `textarea` is `text`....if you are asking how the information can be rendered (assuming all is correct with redux), you could create components that would render the values from redux. if the bot and user messages are in different reducers, you may be able to concatenate (and then sort by time)

Comment: I was previously doing the following I had no textUser and textBot only texts I displayed them and passed some props to styledcomp to modify the background color of a bot and user message like this:   {messages.map(message => (
          <Styled.MessageWrapper user={message.user}>
            <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} user={message.user} />
            <Styled.ChatMessage user={message.user}>
              {message.text}
            </Styled.ChatMessage>
          </Styled.MessageWrapper>
        ))}

Comment: they are in the same reducer, would it be better to separate from the bot and the user?

Comment: I think they could be better in same reducer tbh...all depends

Comment: I found this approach interesting. Could you give me an example of how I could start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207127/discussion-between-delis-and-gabriel).

Comment: basically i wanted when a user typed something and sent
textarea is disabled
and then when the bot responds the textarea would be normal, but I don't know how to display the bot and user texts